# Using a variable to extract information from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I apologize since I'm sure this is an obvious issue, but I just can't seem to find the correct search terms to come up with the answer.

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
example<-cbind(rbind(1,2,3),rbind("a","b","c"))
colnames(example)<-c("a","b")
example<-as.data.frame(example)
```

And I want to extract the values from column a using a variable x,

```
x<-a
```

How do I go about this?  When I try:

```
 example$x
```

I get a null. How do I make this work?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do... what do you expect as an output? If you want to get column `a` just use `example$a`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: `$` can't evaluate RHS. You can only use the actual name (not variable) when using `$`. You need to do `example[, x]` instead

Comment: or `[[`.  There is a canonical duplicate for this but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured that this would be a duplicate, but I couldn't find the right keywords I guess.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a is a character:

```
x <- "a"
example[,x]
```